# Is IList really a better alternative to an array

Tags: c#, arrays, .net-3.5

Today I read a post from Eric Lippert that describes [the harm of arrays](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/22/arrays-considered-somewhat-harmful/). It´s mentioned that when we need a collection of values we should provide *values*, not a *variable* that points to a list of values. Thus Eric suggests that whenever we want to return a collection of items in a method, we should return an `IList<T>`, which provides the same as an array, namely it:

1. enables indexed access
2. enables iterating the items
3. is strongly typed

However in contrast to an array the list also provides members that add or remove items and thus modify the collection-object. We could of course wrap the collection into a `ReadOnlyCollection` and return an `IEnumerable<T>` but then we´d lose the indexed accessability. Moreover a caller can´t know if the ReSharper-warning "possible iterations of the same enumerations" applies as he doesn´t know that internally that enumeration is just a list wrapped within a `ReadOnlyCollection`. So a caller can´t know if the collection was already materialized or not.

So what I want is a collection of items where the collection itself is immutable (the items however don´t have to be, they won´t on an `IList` neither), meaning we can´t add/remove/insert items to the underlying list. However it seems weird to me returning a `ReadOnlyCollection` from my API, at least I´ve never seen an API doing so.

Thus array seems perfect for my needs, doesn´t it?

Comment: There is also a new interface `IReadOnlyList<T>` for that case...

Comment: @Jehof Sorry, forgot to mention .NET3.5

Comment: An advantage of the `array` is that when you do a `foreach` loop on an `array` reference (I'm talking about the reference, not the concrete object in memory), the compiler automatically transforms it to a `for` loop, which is faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> We could of course wrap the collection into a `ReadOnlyCollection` and return an `IEnumerable<T>`

Why do that? `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` implements `IList<T>`, so unless there's some better approach, declaring a return type of `IList<T>` and returning an instance of `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` seems like a good way to go.

However, it just so happens that in current .NET Framework versions, there is a slightly better way: return an instance of `ReadOnlyCollection<T>`, but specify a return type of `IReadOnlyList<T>`. While `IList<T>` doesn't really promise to allow modification by the caller, `IReadOnlyList<T>` is explicit about the intent.

Comment: Ah, I forgot that it implements that interface. Now when API-clients call `Add` on the returned value, they get an exception, which seems weird but I can live with that I guess. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: @HimBromBeere That's what the IsReadOnly property is about.